# Specify region in GCP console snapshot?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When you use the GUI to make a snapshot with GCP it lets you select the zone & region, when you're doing it via terminal using gcloud compute disks snapshot it only seems to let you select a zone, which is no good for us as the zone includes US & Canada and we have clients with a policy saying all data must be kept in canada. Is there any way to do this via the "gcloud compute disks snapshot" command or is it only available via their GUI, and thus non schedulable?

edit: i think in essence I want to do a regional, and specify the region rather than a multiregional backup from the terminal, but can't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> When you use the GUI to make a snapshot with GCP it lets you select
>   the zone & region

The Google Cloud Console allows you to select either "Multi-regional" or "Regional". There is no option to select region and zone. For Regional, you then select the region.

To quote [Google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#best_practices):

> Snapshots can be stored in either one Cloud Storage multi-regional
>   location, such as asia, or one Cloud Storage regional location, such
>   as asia-south1.

Your statement:

> gcloud compute disks snapshot it only seems to let you select a zone,
>   which is no good for us as the zone includes US & Canada

I think that you are referring to the command line option `--zone`. This option means the location of where the compute engine persistent disk is located and not where the snapshot is stored. Use the `beta` command line option `--storage-location`. See below for examples.

If you want your data to stay in Canada, ensure that your instances and buckets are located in Canada and you select "Regional". In your case, select Montreal (`northamerica-northeast1`). The Montreal region does not include the `US`, but the Multi-regional location is `US`.

If you do not specify a storage location, your snapshot is stored in the multi-regional that is geographically closest to the location of your persistent disk. **In your case, this means `US` for instances in Montreal.**

For example, if your compute engine persistent disk is stored in `northamerica-northeast1` your snapshot will be stored in the `US` multi-regional by default.

To specify a "regional" snapshot from the CLI:

```
gcloud beta compute disks snapshot INSTANCE_NAME --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a --snapshot-names=MY_SNAPSHOT_NAME --storage-location=northamerica-northeast1
```

To specify a "multi-regional" snapshot from the CLI:

```
gcloud beta compute disks snapshot INSTANCE_NAME --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a --snapshot-names=MY_SNAPSHOT_NAME --storage-location=us
```

Note:

- There is no multi-regional location limited to Canada.
- `--zone` means where the compute engine persistent disk is located.
- `--storage-location` means where the snapshot will be stored.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I want to do however if I use for example;

"gcloud beta compute disks snapshot INSTANCE_NAME --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a --snapshot-names=MY_SNAPSHOT_NAME --storage-location=northamerica-northeast1"

 with the correct instance and snapshot name it tells me;

"unrecognized arguments: --storage-location=northamerica-northeast1 (did 
you mean '--trace-token'?)"

and does not list --storage-location in it's list of optional flags

Comment: That error means that you are not adding `beta` to the gcloud command OR you need to update gcloud: `gcloud components update` to add this option.